# CompileAssetCatalog failed for XCode build of React Native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I am a Windows guy so I have a totally foggy idea what am I doing here. I cannot really run XCode. I am using Microsoft Mobile Center to make a build for me. It went through whole compilation but failed in the end with this error message.

```
▸ Compiling LaunchScreen.storyboard
** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileAssetCatalog /Users/ci/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tracker-alpha-ftjoguutzpnihlgvuldnwyyqxjbe/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/tracker-alpha/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/tracker-alpha.app tracker-alpha/Assets.xcassets
(1 failure)
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
```

It's a basic React Native app, no custom code, just trying out compilation after [detaching CRNA to ExpoKit](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/detach.html). You can see whole app in public repo here: https://bitbucket.org/fredyc/tracker/src/f090e39c499204eaf629e4f13dd0f873dae2846e/ios/?at=ios

If someone can try to compile it in real XCode, it might perhaps reveal more information. Anyway here are detailed logs produced by Mobile Center if it can help somehow: https://pastebin.com/9CVrfBRJ